# Regex: How to select the last part in a string of text?

Tags: regex, string

I'm looking to select the last part of of the string, namely the (current address xxxxx)

Here's the data:

> Full Name: John Smith 
>   May Go By: John C Smith 
>   Johnathon Smith 
> Johnny
>   Smith
>  Johnny C Smith
> Age: 45 
> Current Address: 
> 1234 SE 2nd st
>  Los
>   Angeles, CA 12345

Now out of this data I extracted, I literally just want the

> Current Address: 
> 1234 SE 2nd st
>  Los Angeles, CA 1234

But since the address changes with every page I scrape, I want to make sure it just scrapes from the CURRENT ADDRESS: to the end of the string via Regex.

So far I've got

> \w{7}\s\w{7}\s

as a regex but it just selects the Current Address part of the string and I can't figure out what to enter to have it finish off the rest of the string.

edit: I do want to keep the regex code that keeps in the current address part of the string since it's static and the only thing that changes from page to page is the address so I want to make sure whatever regex code will just continue until the string ends.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`(^Current Address:.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/TdUWsF/1/) with Dot Matches Newline Mode enabled

This formatted version of that regex that has the multi-line/dot-matches options added but will not be compatible for *all* flavors of regex, but it will for quite a few: `(?mis)(^Current Address:.+)`

If you decide you don't want to keep the Current Address text, you can do:

`^Current Address:[ ]\r\n(^.+$)+|^Current Address:[ ]\n(^.+$)+`
and only retain [capture-group 1](https://regex101.com/r/jXLBEA/2).

---

#### Edit:

Since .NET was specified in the comments, here is a sample code-snippet generated by RegexBuddy for C# to create an object with all regex matches in a string:

```
MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex("(^Current Address:.+)", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
    if (allMatchResults.Count > 0) {
        // Access individual matches using allMatchResults.Item[]
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: Click on the demos -- you didn't tell us what language you're using, so I can't tell you what flags to use. You should probably tell us what language you're using too in your question. I also had to update the second one.

Comment: My bad, I'm using UBot to enter in these regular expressions and i'm not sure what language it's in. I'm assuming Javascript? but I could be wrong

Comment: Oh, and I didn't discover your demo links until after I had posted my original comment. Thanks for your update

Comment: Did a little digging and it looks like it needs to be .NET flavor of Regex

Comment: Okay, so I tried the (?mis)(^Current Address.+) in Ubot and it worked flawlessly. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great! ^_^ Glad to hear you're unblocked.